# Room Database schema update without data loss

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I have developed one application in Android using Kotlin and it is available on playstore. I have used Room database to store the values. I have following queries:

1. Database schema is changed now, How to I need to handle that. I referred to below tutorial but still not clear to handle the schema change in Migration.
   Visit https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.html
2. How can I test my current application with playstore version?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: 1) How to handle a DB migration will depend on what kind of changes you have made in the schema. Some changes (additive) may not require any action at all, for example. It would help if you posted your before and after schema.

Comment: 2) If you have access to your code from when you built and released the current version in the play store, you can build a debug APK, install it on your test device, then switch back to current code and install over the top of the old version. This will give you a reliable simulation of the user upgrade scenario.

Comment: I need to add couple of new column in table but don't want to loose existing values stored in the table.

Comment: 2) I dont have debug apk file to test. I have only playstore apk file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's quite a complex question but basically you have 2 strategies:

- `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` -> simple to implement but your users will lose their data once the app is updated
- Provide a `Migration`strategy (preferable)

**Case 1 - fallbackToDestructiveMigration**

In your database initialization, simply invoke `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` on your database builder:

```kotlin
database = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        UsersDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
```

In this case, since you have updated your database version (suppose from version 1 to version 2) Room can't find any migration strategy, so it will fallback to distructive migration, tables are **dropped**.

**Case 2 - Smart migration**

Suppose you have a table called "Users" and suppose you added a column to this table in version 2 of your database. Let's call this column "user_score" You should implement `migrate` interface of `Migration` class in order to update your "Users version 1" schema to "Users version 2" schema. To do so, you need an `alter table`, you can write it directly inside the `migrate` method:

```kotlin
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            // Your migration strategy here
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Users ADD COLUMN user_score INTEGER")
        }
    };
```

```kotlin
database =  Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
        UsersDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
        .build();
```

More references here :

- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929
- https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-sqlite-database-migration-b9ad47811d34

Comment: By following these approaches I am able to solve my issue. Thanks for the help and support.

Comment: For testing the application I downloaded the application from playstore and installed my new signed app by following `adb install -r <path for apk>` and it updates the app.

Comment: I followed **Case 2 - Smart migration** to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @RajivRanjan happy to hear that! Best wishes for your app!

Comment: Then why it removes the table which scheme wasn't changed? I've added new tables to the same database and increased version but it deleted old unchanged tables

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Hi how to update data in existing database without change structure?

Comment: @Nitin Karale. You need to follow the case 2 and handling migrations

Answer (score 3):

From **room version 2.4.0**, you can easily update using autoMigrations.

DATABASE CLASS

```
@Database(
    version = 3,
    autoMigrations = [
        AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2),
        AutoMigration(from = 2, to = 3)
    ],
    .....
)
```

DATA CLASS

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class DataUser(
    ....
    // I added this column, like this
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "")var test: String = ""  
)
```

see reference below

[android developer: room version2.4.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_240_3)

[android developer: autoMigration](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/AutoMigration)

Answer (score 1):

For your question 2, you can do the following things:

1. Download and install apk file in mobile device from playstore.
2. Build your apk file(signed apk). Before generating the apk file
       don't forget to increase version code.
3. install the signed apk file in device by following below `adb` command

   `adb install -r "apk_file_path"`

Hope this will work.

Comment: I tried the same approach to test the application and it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score -4):

You should use a VCS (like git). For each version of your app you should create a tag, so you can easily switch between published versions to test compatibility.

The migration itself can be done by invoking raw queries on the room database in your migration. If you don't know how to write those, you should first read some tutorials about SQL.